# How To Change Style Of QML Component at runtime?

Tags: qt, qml

I have Written a QT Application which has a Circular Gauge

```
CircularGauge {
        id: circularGauge
        style: CircularGaugeStyle {
            needle: Rectangle {
                y: outerRadius * 0.15
                implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.03
                implicitHeight: outerRadius * 0.9
                antialiasing: true
                color: Qt.rgba(0.66, 0.3, 0, 1)
            }
            minimumValueAngle: -145
            maximumValueAngle: 145
        }
        tickmarksVisible: true
    }
```

I want to change value of minimumValueAngle and maximumValueAngle at runtime.
Is it possible to change style of component in qml at runtime

Comment: you just need to know when you want to apply such change. you can try to link via an Component.onCompleted: { minimumValueAngle= -x; ...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the style item isn't accessible from outside you should do that in a declarative way, for example:

```
CircularGauge {
    id: circularGauge
    property int minValue: -145
    property int maxValue: 145        
    style: CircularGaugeStyle {
        id: circularGaugeStyle
        minimumValueAngle: circularGauge.minValue
        maximumValueAngle: circularGauge.maxValue
    }
}

Button {
    text: "Change values"
    onClicked: {
        circularGauge.minValue = -90;
        circularGauge.maxValue = 90;
    }
}
```